# Restore contentOffset in React Native after paging?

Tags: react-native

In my react native FlatList, I determine when the scrollTo has almost reached the end.  When it reaches the end, my Query will "shift", to include the next page results (and keeping half of the current one).

For example, let's say my initial query returns 20 items, from: 
`[100 ... 80]`

As user reaches the end (80), my query will shift to [90...70], and I run:

`this.setState({ flatListData: newArray });`

The result is good -- the entire FlatList changes.  However, the problem is that my table is now *all the way at the bottom, and 70 is shown* (immediately jumping to the end of the data array).

My desired behavior is that -- as the user reaches 80 and new results of [90...70] come in, I want the position to be locked at 80 (no change in scrollView), so that the user can scroll from 79 to 70 himself.

Comment: So if I understand.... you just want to snap back to the top of the FlatList after you have loaded the newArray value?

Comment: No, I want to snap back to where the trigger was activated (in this case, cell 80). The list starts at 100...80, then, when user hits 80, query changes, and new data is now 90...70.  Instead of the table being "at the end" (ending at 70), I would like the end to be 80 (the point where the user left off).

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the data.